# Why is NHibernate do roundtrip to the database with session.Load()

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, proxy

I use

```
var ap = new ActivityAppointment() {Activity = this.Session.Load<Activity>(appointmentId)};
```

to create a DTO ActivityAppointment to save it to the database.

ActivityAppointment has a reference to Activity, which I set with session.Load() - but now, I have determined, that NHibernate is doing a roundtrip to the database when I call session.Load(). I except, that NHibernate is only creating a proxy-object, which I can assign as a reference to the DTO which has to be saved.

I have also tried it with a appointmentId which does not exists - then I get a exception

```
{"No row with the given identifier exists[Prayon.Entities.Activity#df659e2d-6f96-446f-b6ca-452816732a6c]"}  System.Exception {NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException}
```

I think, NHibernate doesn't know this when It doesn't do a roundtrip to the database - which I think should be the case with session.Load() - or am I wrong?

Comment: http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a lazy loading disabled (e.g. <class name="Activity" lazy="false">)?

If you are eager, load goes to the DB, because there is no proxy (see this question [NHibernate does not create proxy unless lazy=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968590/nhibernate-does-not-create-proxy-unless-class-lazy-true)). No proxy -> sessionLoad hits DB -> unrecoverable exception.

[Official documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading):

> Note that Load() will throw an unrecoverable exception if there is no matching database
>   row. If the class is mapped with a proxy, Load() returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and does not actually hit the database until you invoke a method of the object. This behaviour is very useful if you wish to create an association to an object without actually loading it from the database.